# Regex negative lookahead (PCRE)

Tags: regex, pcre, email-validation

I'm trying to create a PCRE to match email From lines with a realname that does not match the address in angle brackets. I know it's trivial in code, but this needs to work in regex.

Most people put their realname in a From line, such as:

```
Bob Jones <bob@example>
```

But spammers will often try to fake a recipient into opening email my pretending to be from Bob by using his email address in the realname using a compromised account:

```
bob@example.com <susie@domain.com>
```

I'm trying to write a PCRE regex that would recognize email From lines where the realname is an email address and that does not match the address in angled brackets.

Here's what we have (intentionally over-simplified)

```
/([^@]+@[^\s]+) <(?!\1)>/
```

The problem is that `(?!\1)` is a zero-width negative look-ahead, which does not consume the address in angled brackets.  The above currently only matches when the angled brackets are empty, ie: `<>`.

Does anyone have any advice?

Should NOT match:

```
Bob Jones <bob@example.com>
bob@example.com <bob@example.com>
```

Should match:

```
bob@example.com <susie@domain.com>
```

Comment: Are you trying to match the bad emails lines?

Comment: Yes.  Most people do not put email address in the `realname` part of the email address. But it is not categorical illegal. If they do enter an email address in realname, it MUST match the actual email address in angled brackets.

Comment: Its simply your regex with an extra thing `/([^@]+@[^\s]+) <(?!\1)[^@]+@[^\s]+>/` Note however, your regex is problematic.

Comment: Btw, assertions can't consume.

Comment: Understood.  We have run into that roadblock. FYI -- the example you suggested does not work either.

Comment: Actually, it's not my regex. It's problematic like said. A little tweak for lines and it matches the bad stuff https://regex101.com/r/5HNRbx/1

Comment: And this as well https://regex101.com/r/5HNRbx/2